# Passing a file that hasn't been created, as input -- Python

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I'm attempting to create a script that pulls an html table using pandas, doing some other intermediary steps, and then transposing the data into an Excel file.

The problem is, I want to pass the website, the ship's name, and then the subsequent filename that is created into the script but it keeps erroring out stating the file doesn't exist. I know it doesn't exist because it hasn't been created by the program.

**Is there a way to run through the script passing the intended filename to be created as input?** Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import openpyxl

#This segment of code initially grabs the webpage from the website
webpage = input("Enter the webpage here: ")
ship_name = input("Enter the name of the ship here: ")

df = pd.read_html(webpage, skiprows=[7,14,15,16], index_col=None)
df[0].to_excel(ship_name + ".xlsx")

#This code segment does an initial clean up of the data: Gets rid of copied column data that comes over due to the colspan=3 tag in the original html source code
filename = ("aase.xlsx")
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
sheet = wb['Sheet1']
status = sheet.cell(sheet.min_row, 1).value
print(status)
sheet.delete_rows(1)
sheet.delete_cols(3,2)
wb.save(filename)
```

Comment: See the first example [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html) for how to create a new workbook.

Comment: Is `"aase.xlsx"` different to `shipname + ".xlsx"`? If it is then the code makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling this:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
```

Create a blank workbook in memory:

```
wb = Workbook()
```

Then `save` it later.

You could also refer to the ["Simple Usage" documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html) for a clearer example of this.